# Intersect two ranges in Swift

Tags: generics, swift, interval

Can you think of a reason the following extension should not be used in production, or a better way of implementing it:

```
public extension Range {

    @warn_unused_result
    public func intersect(other: Range) -> Range {

        let ds = startIndex.distanceTo(other.startIndex)
        let de = startIndex.distanceTo(other.endIndex)

        let s = ds <= 0 ? startIndex : startIndex.advancedBy(ds, limit: endIndex)
        let e = de <= 0 ? startIndex : startIndex.advancedBy(de, limit: endIndex)

        return s..<e
    }
}
```

The method should pass the following assertions:

```
(5...7).intersect(9...9) == (8..<8) // ....|||.---..
(5...7).intersect(1...3) == (5..<5) // ....---.|||..

(5...7).intersect(8...9) == (8..<8) // ....|||---...
(5...7).intersect(1...4) == (5..<5) // ....---|||...

(5...7).intersect(7...9) == (7..<8) // ....||+--....
(5...7).intersect(1...5) == (5..<6) // ....--+||....

(5...7).intersect(6...9) == (6..<8) // ....|++-.....
(5...7).intersect(1...6) == (5..<7) // ....-++|.....

(5...7).intersect(6...6) == (6..<7) // ....|+|......
(5...7).intersect(4...8) == (5..<8) // ....-+++-....
```

Note the first four assertions with an empty intersection: the method is currently returning `startIndex..<startIndex` if the `other` range is on the "left", or `endIndex..<endIndex` if it is on the "right". Is this a reasonable behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a general problem: The 
[`distanceTo(_: Self) -> Self.Distance`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_ForwardIndexType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/ForwardIndexType/s:FPs16ForwardIndexType10distanceToFxwx8Distance) of the
`ForwardIndexType` protocol requires that

> - `start` and `end` are part of the same sequence when conforming to `RandomAccessSequenceType`.
> - `end` is reachable from `self` by incrementation otherwise.

(and `RandomAccessSequenceType` is probably a typo and should be
`RandomAccessIndexType`).

Here is a simple example where this conditions are not met, and
your code crashes:

```
let r1 = "foo".rangeOfString("")!
print(r1) // 1..<5
let r2 = "bar".rangeOfString("")!
print(r2) // 2..<6
let r = r1.intersect(r2) // fatal error: cannot increment endIndex
```

Incrementing the start index of `r1` never hits the start index
of `r2`.

Here is another example:

```
struct MyIndex: ForwardIndexType {
    let value: Int

    func successor() -> MyIndex {
        return MyIndex(value: self.value + 1)
    }
}

func == (lhs: MyIndex, rhs: MyIndex) -> Bool {
    return lhs.value == rhs.value
}
```

is an index which can only be incremented. Then

```
let r1 = Range(MyIndex(value: 4) ... MyIndex(value: 6))
let r2 = Range(MyIndex(value: 3) ... MyIndex(value: 5))
let r = r1.intersect(r2)
```

will loop forever, because incrementing `MyIndex(value: 4)` 
never reaches `MyIndex(value: 3)`.

So intersecting ranges makes only sense if both ranges refer
to the same sequence. I don't know if that can be ensured at 
compile time with a suitable restriction, I assume that it is 
not possible. It should at least be *documented* (similar to the
above mentioned requirements of `ForwardIndexType`).

You could restrict the method to ranges of integer elements

```
public extension Range where Element : IntegerType { ... }
```

but of course that reduces its usability considerably.

The implementation itself looks good to me. The behavior in the case
of an empty intersection it a sensible choice. Is similar to that of the [`clamp()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_ClosedInterval_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/structm/ClosedInterval/s:FVs14ClosedInterval5clampFGS_x_GS_x_) 
method of `ClosedInterval`:

```
ClosedInterval(3, 4).clamp(ClosedInterval(5, 6)) // 4 ... 4
ClosedInterval(3, 4).clamp(ClosedInterval(1, 2)) // 3 ... 3
```

which returns the left or right bound, depending on wether the other
interval lies on the left or on the right.

If your ranges just represent intervals and do not refer to indices
of sequences, then `ClosedInterval` (and the existing `clamp()` method) might be an alternative.

Comment: Did you see this: `r1.contains(r2.startIndex) // false`, where `r1` and `r2` are from your range of string example? Again, thanks for drawing my attention to this!

Answer (score 0):

Martin's excellent insight into the nature of the problem got me thinking if we could do any better than `extension Range where Element : IntegerType`. Here is one possibility:

```
public extension Range where Element : Comparable {

    @warn_unused_result
    public func intersect(other: Range) -> Range {
        guard endIndex > other.startIndex else {
            return endIndex..<endIndex
        }
        guard other.endIndex > startIndex else {
            return startIndex..<startIndex
        }
        let s = other.startIndex > startIndex ? other.startIndex : startIndex
        let e = other.endIndex < endIndex ? other.endIndex : endIndex
        return s..<e
    }
}
```

This at least passes Martin's range of string test.

Of course, when working with strings we must take the usual precautions since:

```
let s1 = "foo"
let s2 = "bar"

let r1 = s1.characters.indices      // 0..<7
r1.count                            // 4
s1.utf16.count                      // 7

let i = r1.startIndex      // 0
i.successor().successor()  // 5 (i therefore holds reference to s1!!!)
```

This means that even though the `intersect` method does what it's supposed to:

```
import Foundation

let flag1r = s1.rangeOfString("")!            // 1..<5
let flag2r = s2.rangeOfString("")!            // 2..<6
let intersection  = flag1r.intersect(flag2r)    // 2..<5
```

The result may still be surprising if you then use it to:

```
s1[flag1r]          // ""
s1[flag2r]          // "�o"
s1[intersection]    // "�"
```

This is because:

```
let u = "".unicodeScalars
    .map{ "\\u{\(String($0.value, radix: 16))}" }
    .joinWithSeparator("")

print(u)                // \u{1f1e9}\u{1f1f0}

"\u{1f1e9}\u{1f1f0}"    // 
"\u{1f1e9}"             // 
"\u{1f1f0}"             //
```

Personally, I believe that the String API should guaranty that the following is always true:

```
string.characters.indices.description == (0..<string.characters.count).description
```

... and NOT, as it is currently the case:

```
string.characters.indices.description == (0..<string.utf16.count).description
```

... simply because `Character` in swift represents extended grapheme clusters, not utf code points.

The fundamental problem, though, which goes beyond String API, is that the collection index is not currently a scalar value, but also holds a reference to its collection! [Swift 3.0 is set to completely rethink indexing throughout the language](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0065-collections-move-indices.md), so we are yet to see whether we will no longer have to deal with these complexities (unless we explicitly want to).

Note, however, that this particular issue does not (in itself) make the `intersect` method on ranges wrong, though it does require the same care that `rangeOfString` requires when you are using it to cast a view into a collection whose index type has a dodgy sense of `successor()`.

Comment: `Element : Comparable` is a good idea, I did not think of that. I think that it can be simplified (using less comparisons). If you want this code reviewed again then you can post it as a follow-up question instead of an answer (compare http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for the various options).

Comment: Sorry for not responding sooner (I was in transit). Yeah, I typed that out in  a hurry with half a brain. I suppose this one is just too easy to see and doesn't really deserve another code review. Would you mind if I update this answer with a more efficient code?

Comment: Why should I? It is your question and self-answers are welcome. Just make sure to meet the standards for an answer: describe what you changed and why.

Comment: The value of intersecting "unrelated" ranges is still questionable. In the string example, `r` has no meaning for either of the strings.

Comment: Certainly... I appended to the answer some thoughts on the topic.